# To set the path to the directory containing the Elixir module in VS Code

Tags: terminal, path, compilation, elixir

I have installed the ElixirLS Extension. I need help with opening the IEx session from the directory containing the Elixir module.  Kindly help in setting the path

checkout.ex

```
defmodule Checkout do
  def total_cost(price, tax_rate) do
    price * (tax_rate + 1)
  end
end
```

```
MacBook-Pro:elixir-intro sudha$ elixirc checkout.ex
MacBook-Pro:elixir-intro sudha$ iex
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.14.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Checkout.total_cost(100,0.2)

this is what I got -

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Checkout.total_cost/2 is undefined (module Checkout is not available)
    Checkout.total_cost(100, 0.2)
    iex:1: (file)
iex(1)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file in the `iex` session. Try either:
`iex -r checkout.ex` or inside of `iex` try `c "checkout.ex"`